# Searchable dictionary not working in hardware tests

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

Using the sample Searchable Dictionary I have created a custom dictionary that works perfectly when I run it in AVD. But when I hook up my Android device (Motorola Droid) the search states no search results found (but it appears to be working). I have debugging turned on in the Android manifest and on my device. It does not appear to be reading the definitions.txt. Any advice on this would be helpful